# axistools-maven-plugin not generating source from WSDL

Tags: web-services, maven-3, apache-axis, java-ee-6

I am using Apache Axis to generate the java source from my WSDL file. The maven run was successful without any errors but no generated classes.

**Question**: What am I missing here?

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>/src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>thesourcewsdlfile.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I am clearly not sure what is the problem with this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define source and output directory bases on your maven project, that is, using standard maven properties to point to the right absolute path at runtime, changing your configuration as following:

```
 <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
 <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
```

Based on this configuration, the `thesourcewsdlfile.wsdl` is supposed to be located under `src/main/resources/thesourcewsdlfile.wsdl`

The full plugin configuration should hence be:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>thesourcewsdlfile.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Moreover, the following dependencies must be added to the project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

As a general note, it would be much better to place generated sources under the `target` directory, since they are generated automatically and should not be added to the version control in use. A standard location would then be any desired (meaningful) directory under `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources` (where `${project.build.directory}` is the standard property pointing to the `target` directory indeed).

Comment: I am getting `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java` when I give the absolute path as mentioned above. Running without any source files when i remove it.

Comment: @ArunRaj check my update, it tried it and works fine now.

Comment: I tried it but same error: `A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin:1.4:wsdl2java: org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java`                     Is it a maven issue?

Comment: check whether the `axis-1.4.jar` is in your local maven cache, there may be a `.lastUpdated` file. Actually, as a double check, search and remove all `.lastUpdated` files in your `m2/repository` directory, then retry a Maven build.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are  missing the  **wsdl** folder  under  **resources**, just add it and  run:

```
mvn clean generate-sources
```